# Manipulation of list - Extract integers to new list

Tags: python, integer

I have a list which consist of string and integers. I have to pop only integers and put that in a separate list. **My code**:

```
list1=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h',1,2,3]
list=[]
x=0
for i in list1:
     if isinstance(i,int) :
        list.append(i)
        list1.pop(x)
     x += 1

print(list1)
print(list)
```

**Output of above code**

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 2]
[1, 3]
```

**My question is:** Why are all the integers not removed by my code? What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Do **not** manipulate a list while iterating over it...

Comment: What vale holds x?

Comment: index value of list1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *iterate* and *manipulate* the same list at the same time:

```
for i in list1:            # iteration
    if isinstance(i,int):
        list.append(i)
        list1.pop(x)       # manipulate
     x += 1
```

This usually does not work: the `for` loop works with a cursor. If you meanwhile removes an item, you thus will start skipping elements.

It is better to simply use a *declarative* and *Pythonic* approach, like for instance the following:

```
list_int = [i for i in list1 if isinstance(i,int)]
list1 = [i for i in list1 if not isinstance(i,int)]
```

Furthermore you should not name a variable `list`, since then you remove the reference to the `list` class.

Comment: it works!!
but is it possible to modify "list1" Willem ji?

Comment: @geeksam: not without the iteration getting into trouble. Note that popping from a list is furthermore an *O(n)* operation. So even if that was possible, it would result in an *O(n^2)* algorithm.